# How can I remove the mold/odor from my roommates desk cabinet where onions started rotting in a plastic bag?

Tags: wood, cleaning, mold, laminate

My university roommate left some onions in a plastic bag in his desks cabinet while he left for winter break. After figuring out where the smell was coming from, I found that the onions had begun to rot, or do whatever it is that onions do.

The plastic bag probably did a good amount to shield the environment but the cabinet still smells days after removing the originating cause (I threw out the onions), and is causing the room to smell. What should I do to sanitize it and remove odors, so that it stops bothering my nose and lungs?

The desk is made of what I imagine is called laminated wood. If it was plastic or metal I might have a better idea of what to do.

Pictures of cabinet:
[image: cabinet door]
[image: cabinet internals]

Comment: Wipe the surfaces down with vinegar. Soak some cloths in vinegar, place them in an open plastic bag and close the door. Replace the vinegar as the cloths dry out.

Comment: Oh, good, replace the rotten onion smell with horrible vinegar smell? Not sure I'd buy into that, @DelphicOracle...

Answer (score 1):

As [stated in a comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/289491/how-can-i-remove-the-mold-odor-from-my-roommates-desk-cabinet-where-onions-start#comment608447_289491) by [DelphicOracle](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/169107/delphicoracle), clean all surfaces.  The comment suggests using vinegar and then leaving some vinegar soaked rags:

> Wipe the surfaces down with vinegar. Soak some cloths in vinegar, place them in an open plastic bag and close the door. Replace the vinegar as the cloths dry out.

I'd suggest using baking soda instead of vinegar to soak up the smell (diluted vinegar is still great for cleaning).  Pour some into a cup or other container or use the [Arm & Hammer deodorizer box](https://www.armandhammer.com/en/baking-soda/deodorizers/fridge-and-freezer-deodorizers/fresh-n-natural-odor-absorber-14-oz) that is designed for that purpose.  Note that any baking soda will work.  The box just saves you having to put it into an open container.  Toss the baking soda when done.

You also may want to air out the cabinet when you're not there.  If you don't mind the smell of vinegar, leave an open container of it outside the cabinet to mask the smell when you are there.  This would work for me (I like the smell of vinegar) but not for everyone.  I've found this effective against skunk smell.

Comment: I mean, you could try bleach instead of vinegar...